# Django: Page Not Found

Tags: python, django, http-status-code-404

I'm getting a 404 from Django and none of the previous posts on the subject (of which there are many) seem to have helped.

views.py

```
from django.views.generic.detail import DetailView, SingleObjectMixin
from app.models import MyModel

class MyDetails(DetailView, SingleObjectMixin):
    template_name = "app/my_view.html"
    model = MyModel
```

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib   import admin
from app.views import MainList, post_form_upload, MyDetails

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', MainList.as_view(), name="main_list"),
    url(r'^add_something$', post_form_upload, name="add_something"),
    url(r'^my_details/(?P<pk>\d+)$', MyDetails.as_view(), name="my_details"),
]
```

app/urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls  import url
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib   import admin

urlpatterns = [
    (r'^$', include('app.urls')),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
]
```

when I enter the URL: http://localhost:8000/my_details, I get the following error:

```
Using the URLconf defined in app.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:
^$ [name='main_list']
^add_something$ [name='add_something']
^my_details/(?P<pk>\d+)$ [name='my_details']
The current URL, my_details, didn't match any of these.
```

The other two URLs (/ and /add_something) work fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, not sure how you are not running into this issue, but in your `app/urls.py`

```
(r'^$', include('app.urls')),
```

should be

```
(r'^/', include('app.urls')),
```

`$` indicates the end of regex pattern, and anything inside `include()` would not be included.

Secondly, None of your URL patterns match `my_details/` They only match `my_details/<id>`

A little more on the documentation of [URL regex, etc..](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/http/urls/#example)

Comment: I was totally misunderstanding what (?P<pk>\d+) meant...I was trying my_details?id=3 etc

Comment: You should be doing `my_details/3/`

Comment: Yeh, thanks. Now that I've done that, is there something I need to add to the views.py? The page is now rendering, but it looks like the {{ model.id }} in the template is blank...do I need to manually retrieve the model object?

Comment: Yes, you would have to send the `model` object to the template through the "context" : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/templates/api/#rendering-a-context

Comment: I was under the impression that DetailView and SingleObjectMixin handled this somehow

Comment: Oh.. you are doing class based views. But you still need to tell it what object to render correct?

Comment: Makes sense...I'm very new to Django (i.e. yesterday), how should I handle this?

Comment: A good opportunity to learn: https://hellowebapp.com/news/introduction-to-class-based-views/ (A neat tutorial on CBV) - It is pretty straight forward.

Comment: Ok, so it turns out I didn't need to hook up the object to the context...I was defining {{ model.id }} in the template because of model = Thing...turns out I needed to define {{ thing.id }} ...lots of convention going on under the hood